# Recursive function to iterative function as binoms

Tags: java, loops, recursion

I'm new with algorithms and wonder how this displayed function is supposed to be converted/transformed from recursive to iterative. What should I keep in mind when converting?

```
public int binom(int n, int k)
{
    if (k == 0 || n == k) { return 1; }

    return binom(n - 1, k - 1) + binom(n - 1, k);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, this problem is not so easy, if you just look at the recursive code and try to decrypt it.
However, it might be a helpful hint for you, that  (n over k), i.e. the binomial coefficient can be written as

```
n! / (k! * (n - k)!)
```

where "!" denotes the factorial.
And it should be rather easy to compute the factorial in a Loop (i.e. iterative) for you.

If intermediate results are too big you can shorten before computation. You can shorten either term k! or the term (n-k)! (you would choose the bigger one). For example with n = 5 and k = 3 you have:
(1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5) / ((1 * 2 * 3) * (1 * 2)) = (4 * 5) / (1 * 2)

Spoiler-Alarm:

```
public static int binomial(int n, int k) {
    int nMinusK = n - k;
    if (n < nMinusK) {
        //Switch n and nMinusK
        int temp = n;
        n = nMinusK;
        nMinusK = temp;
    }

    int result = 1;

    //  n!/k!
    for (int i = k + 1; i <= n; i++) {
        result *= i;
    }

    //Division by (n-k)!
    for (int j = 1; j <= nMinusK; j++) {
        result = result / j;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Okey thanks! What do you mean by shorten, and exaktly how would it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiplicative form of binomial coefficients, for example from [Wikia](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), which can be easily implemented with faculties or loops.

[image: Binomial coefficient multiplicative formula]

Comment: I have done this with faculties, but for larger numbers, int or long won't support it, faculties are too large and not so preferable.

Comment: You can use `BigInteger`, which supports large numbers on the heap. Furthermore, you can split the multiplication and division up in several factors, so you will have smaller numbers.